# Unable to update the gradle version for particular project : Android Studio

Tags: android, java-8, build, build.gradle, retrolambda

I am using the following versions
Android studio: 3.5.1

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.7.1'

project.ext.minSdkVersion = 21
project.ext.compileSdkVersion = 27
project.ext.buildToolsVersion = '27.0.3'
project.ext.supportLibVersion = '27.0.0'
```

and in app gradle

```
dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

and gradle wrraper properties are:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip
```

Now I want to update project gradle.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.7.1'// we cannot use it for gradle updated versions 

project.ext.minSdkVersion = 21
project.ext.compileSdkVersion = 28
project.ext.buildToolsVersion = '28.0.2'
project.ext.supportLibVersion = '28.0.0'
```

Here it shows errors on the removal of retrolambda showing compileOptions remove which is affecting to the lambda methods of the project.

Whenever I am trying to update gradle version only 3.0.0 without any other project ext updates its showing me the binding errors BR.

[image]

Please check all dependencies in gradle.

```
dependencies {
    //    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLibVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$rootProject.supportLibVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:customtabs:$rootProject.supportLibVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$rootProject.supportLibVersion"
    //mvp library
    compile 'de.appsfactory:mvp:2.+'
    //date and time joda library
    compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.10.3'
    compile 'com.shawnlin:number-picker:2.4.2'
    compile 'net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:5.2.0'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:greendao:3.2.2'
    compile 'com.reginald.swiperefresh:library:1.1.2'
    compile 'io.swagger:swagger-annotations:1.5.24'
    compile 'net.openid:appauth:0.7.0'//unable to update 0.7.1
    //dynamically dimensions library
    compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:24.1-android'//unable to update 24.1-jre
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:16.0.1'

    //multidex
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.wrbug:editspinner:1.1.0'

    compile('cn.trinea.android.view.autoscrollviewpager:android-auto-scroll-view-pager:1.1.2') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.2'
    //rxble library
    compile 'com.polidea.rxandroidble2:rxandroidble:1.10.3'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.8'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.rx2:replaying-share:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0'

    //photo libraries
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.3'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'


}
```

I am getting errors like : 
error: package com.android.databinding.library.baseAdapters does not exist 
error: cannot find symbol class BR

Comment: can you update the question with the error screen

Comment: Please check the error screen.

Comment: Have you tried with clean and rebuild the project ?@porwalshweta24

Comment: try files->invalidate caches /Restart

Comment: Yes, I have done this but not working for me.  Soham and Sharon

Comment: Can you post the code of the file where it is giving the error.It's hard to guess with the screenshot only.@porwalshweta24

Comment: have you using firebase .?

Comment: can you update full screen of build.gradle screen

Comment: please check dependencies. @BADSHAH

Comment: Upgrade gradle version 3.3.2